# Flask doesn't print to console

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask, and I'm trying to add print info to debug server side code.
When launch my flask app with debug=True, i can't get any info print to console

I tried to use logging instead, but no success.
So how to debug flask program with console.

```
@app.route('/getJSONResult', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getJSONResult():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        uut = request.form['uut']
        notes = request.form['notes']
        temperature = request.form['temperature']

        logging.info("enter getJSONReuslt")
        print('enter getJSONReuslt')
        filter_by_query = {k: v for k, v in {
            'uut': uut, 'notes': notes, 'temperature': temperature}.items() if v != ""}
        s = session.query(UUT_TEST_INFO).filter_by(**filter_by_query).first()
        return jsonify(s.serialize)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = ''.join(random.choice(
        string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(32))
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)


> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2017 15:20:48] "GET /qyer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2017 15:20:48] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2017 15:20:48] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2017 15:20:51] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2017 15:21:58] "POST /getJSONResult HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I fixed server side 500 error issue, now request get 200 code, and console displays following info

```
$ python project.py
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger pin code: 158-624-607
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2017 11:33:33] "GET /qyer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:root:Enter getJSONResult
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2017 11:33:43] "POST /getJSONResult HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Still no info from print command

Comment: Please update your question with your code

Comment: what is the 500 error? Put a print just after `def getJSONResult():` line.

Comment: @hjpotter92 500 post request timeout. it seems programs is stuck in getJSONResult, and doesn't get a return value, and it blocks all actions, even if i put print at first line of funtion. I try to return a simple string, everything works, but it doesn't help me debug the problem...

Comment: @X.Z What exactly is the problem - you can't print to console in debug mode or you can't put logs because I can see both things in your code.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this and see if it helps:

For python2:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

print('This is error output', file=sys.stderr)
print('This is standard output', file=sys.stdout)
```

For python3 you don't need to import from **future** print_function:

```
import sys

print('This is error output', file=sys.stderr)
print('This is standard output', file=sys.stdout)
```

See if it helps to print to console.

Comment: But what is the cause?

Comment: not sure why, but this doesn't work for me in python 3.6.8

Comment: Nice! It helped me to create a debug function which writes in apache error log file.

Answer (score 80):

You can force to flush stdout directly from print:

```
print('enter getJSONReuslt', flush=True)
```

This way you don't have to print to `sys.stderr` (which flushes by default).

The reason for your problem is line buffering. Line buffering makes I/O more efficient with the drawback of not immediately showing prints under some conditions.

Comment: Works for me on Windows

Answer (score 21):

By default the level for logging is warning. So you won't see a logging message of level `DEBUG`. To fix this just enable debug logging with the `basicConfig()` function of the logging module:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: it works. i can see logging infomation. but still i can't print any thing to my console

Comment: printing should actually work all the time. Maybe you get an error before reaching the print function.

Comment: @X.Z Can you show the full stacktrace when 500 error occurs?

Comment: @Nurzhan, I fixed 500 error issue, and successfully got returned data from getJSONResult function, but stiil, i can't print any info to console

Comment: I can concur. After `app = Flask(__name__)`, I can not print anything. even some of my classes extending `MethodView` are not getting called.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the app instance in development mode, because the logging level is set to DEBUG, ie.:

```
app.logger.info('This is info output')
```

In production mode you need to use a more severe level or you can set the logging level to DEBUG, ie.:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    app.logger.info('Processing default request')
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This article talks about logging into flask: https://www.scalyr.com/blog/getting-started-quickly-with-flask-logging/

Answer (score 13):

Had the same printing problem. Using `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print` solved the issue.

Comment: This seems to work for me, but I still can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Flask may not be printing to console because you may have more than one instances of the website being served. Look at your other terminals and make sure it is not running somewhere else; print statements may be being sent to the other instance.