# Flask doesn't print to console (route)

Tags: flask

There is already [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405708/flask-doesnt-print-to-console) with the same question that has an answer, but it doesn't work for me. There is also [no explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405708/flask-doesnt-print-to-console#comment90698871_44426319) given what causes the problem.

Flask version: 1.0.2., running locally.

Route:

```
@bp.route("/mailbox/get_mail_attachment", methods = ["GET"])
@token_auth.login_required
def get_mail_attachment():
    print("it should print")
    return error_response(400)
```

I'm getting back a response with status code 400, but the route doesn't print to the console (all other routes of my application do). It is the right route though, because if I change the url of the route I get back 404.

I guess it doesn't matter where the request comes from, but maybe I'm wrong: In my case it comes from an Angular application (version 5).

The request looks like this:

```
getAttachment(data) {
    const url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}` + '/mailbox/get_mail_attachment';
    const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')})
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: data, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
}
```

I simplified code of the flask route, that's why it doesn't make any use of the request.args.

Comment: What happens if your user is not logged in?

Comment: Are you sure the 400 is actually originating from the `return error_response(400)` line, and not from flask internally (e.g. by accessing `request.form['key_which_is_not_sent_in_form']` (which also causes a 400)? Try using error code 418 instead and see if your angular app can see this error code.

Comment: I tried to simplify the code in order to check the code without auth, it doesn't work without the auth either. If I change the status code to 418 (smart suggestion!), it returns 418 - so that's not the cause. For whatever strange reason it works "sometimes", but completely randomly and only just once. So it prints once, and then not anymore until quite some time goes by. Reminds me of the behaviour of a browser cache.